# CocoaPodsのsetupでThe `master` repo is not a git repo.のエラー 解決法はありますか

Tags: swift, realm, cocoapods

### 前提・実現したいこと

マックのターミナルで `pod setup` を実行:

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
```

Realm を CocoaPods で setup して使いたい。

---

### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

エラーの内容:

```sh
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.
[!] The `master` repo is not a git repo.
```

---

### 試したこと

1. `xcode-select --install`
2. gem バージョンアップ
   現在の gem version →　2.6.7
3. ネット上の検索
4. Mac OSのバージョンをダウングレード
   macOS High Sierra から Sierra10.12.6。

---

### 補足情報 (OS, ツールのバージョンなど)

- MacBookPro OS は Sierra10.12.6
- Swift 4

Comment: Xcodeが正しく認識されていません。Xcodeを再インストールして１度起動すれば直るように思います。`xcode-select --install`はすでに試されたということですが、そのコマンド成功してますか？何かエラーが出ませんでしたか？

Comment: エラーは次のようなものでした。**①xcode-select --installを実行**すると
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
**②「 gem update」を実行**すると
Updating installed gems
Updating activesupport
Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.0.5.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
自分のパソコンですけど、書き込みできないのでしょうか。

Comment: `/Library`以下のディレクトリはシステムディレクトリなので変更には管理者権限が必要ですね。`sudo`をつければ成功すると思いますが、そこは今のところ問題に関係ないと思います。`git`コマンドは成功しますか？

Comment: Xcodeをインストールし直しても同じエラーでした。gitコマンドに対しても下記のエラーが出ます。xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.

Comment: Xcodeが起動するならXcode>Preference...>LocationsのCommand Line Toolsのところで適切なXcodeを選択してください。まずXcodeのパスが`"/Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app`となっているのを直す必要があります。Xcode9.0.1.appというのはすでに無いんですよね？

Comment: 既にありません。xcode9.0.1と書き換えて使っていたものなので、これが原因かなと思い元に戻していました。御教示いただいたようにLocationsのCommand Line Toolsのところを見ると空欄でした。これを選択し直したところ、セットアップができました。感謝します。macOSは、 High Sierra でも良かったんですね。